Image fails to dispalyed in QGIS Popup window
I can view the image path from attribute table but I can't view the image in popup. I can see the image using the identify feature option in toolbar. But I need to display the image in popup as a user information. I can't display it in the popup even though I have add the path in the attribute table.
I used the Html code:
<img src = "file:///[%@project_home%]/filename/[%fieldname%]"/>

